# WordPress Development with MAMP not working since installing MySQL using terminal

Tags: mysql, wordpress, web, mamp

I'm having a problem with localhost servers and databases. I'm by no means a pro at all of this but I've been developing WordPress websites for a short while and have been using MAMP because of how simple it is.

Now I understand that it installs MySQL for you and that Apache and PHP are all included with OS X, but I began learning Ruby on Rails and while I was following a tutorial I installed MySQL manually via terminal and I think I've ran into some collision problems now.

For a while MAMP refused to start the SQL server so I've changed the ports to Apache 8888 and SQL 8889 and now seems to be starting fine (which are the defaults I believe but were different for some reason).

Now I've got two different database locations (I think). One which I can see via the terminal using `mysql -u root -p` and the other which I can see by launching MAMP and viewing PHPMyAdmin. If I create a database in one I cannot see it in the other, but more importantly when I create the database in MAMP's phpMyAdmin and try installing WP it doesn't recognise it, is this because my username/password may have been changed for MAMP or should it all be the same?

So far I've been thinking maybe I should uninstall MAMP and do a hard reset for MySQL etc and just use the terminal to manage MySQL, phpMyAdmin and Apache etc but I'm not sure - is there a better way to go about this? I am working on a WP website for a client at the moment in tandem with a Ruby on Rails project so need to ideally jump between the two!

Comment: If you can and are happy too, ditch mamp and use apache on your machine etc... You are correct in that you now have two instances of MySQL etc... and for Mamp to work you need to stop your local machine one working. So  switching between sites becomes a pain. There are many guides to help set up WordPress without MAMP :) MAMP is great if you run nothing else. Now watch everyone say you should use a VM :D

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts :-) So would I need to transfer existing databases from MAMP to my machine's one? I mean I don't really need them, thinking about it...

So maybe just uninstall MAMP completely, setup a WordPress environment with terminal and go from there?

Comment: Unless you have added in a load of data you might as well start again to be honest :) so yeah uninstall MAMP and go from there.

Comment: Okay great, cheers - I'll have a go, if you know any solid WP tutorials for this then hit me up, otherwise don't worry I'm sure I'll find some, as you said, there are loads :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having had a look around this looks like a good guide for running WordPress on your Mac locally... https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/fastest-way-to-install-wordpress-on-osx-10-6/

They also have nice guides for installing Apache, MySQL and PHP as well for Mavericks https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-9-mavericks/ and Yosemite https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/

Hope these help and good luck :)

Comment: That's great to hear :) glad you got it sorted